# Ubuntu xenial File Manager trash not working

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, trash, thunar, pcmanfm

I am on a fresh ubuntu xenial installation.
I can't make the trash directory working, no matter what file manager I use.
I've tried with nautilus, thunar, pcmanfm (my current file manager): nothing.
None of them is able to access the trash folder.

If I type **Trash:///** in the location bar, I get the message

```
Operation not supported
```

I'm using Openbox, and gvfs and fuse are installed.

I have created a Trash folder in

```
/home/my_user_name/.local/share/Trash
```

and if I move a file to the trash, I can spot it inside the files subdirectory

```
/home/my_user_name/.local/share/Trash/files
```

If I launch pcmanfm with dbus from terminal

```
dbus-launch pcmanfm
```

everything works fine, I can see the trash, the volumes, and the network links in the sidebar.

Any idea?
Please help me, I'm lost!

Thanks

Comment: Did you go through this process?
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager